# Economic Strategy with chances

Tags: probability, optimization

(Disclaimer: I really suck at searching for problems that have probably been answered a thousand times already. And describing a problem isnt really my strong suit either. Sorry if this is a common problem)

So there is this game (Rust) where you need to find "components" to success in the game.
You can either find them or you can clone them on a research bench if you already found one of them.

There is also a kind of currency (scraps) with which you can clone components.

Example: Say you have a component you want to clone (rifle body). This component needs 100 scraps to clone.

But you can gamble. If you put only 50 scraps (half of the scraps needed) into the research bench, you have a 50% chance to clone the component.

What is the best strategy to clone components and be economic about it (saving scraps)?

So at first it thought: Well, always put in 100% of the needed scraps, because in the long run you can only lose scraps.

But what if you do this: Only put 50% of scraps in and if this fails you can try again with 50%. So this only fails 1/4 of the time right? 
But this is bound to happen once in a while... so you lose again.

Or what about putting in 95% always... or trying 30% SOME of the time. I have no clue how to go about this.

So i am really not sure what the best strategy is. Something tells me putting in 100% of the scraps is the best way. But i cant prove it.

(Sorry for this long convoluted post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your objective.  From an expected value point of view, each scrap is worth $0.01$ rifle.  If you try once with $100$ scraps you are guaranteed to have $1$ rifle.  If you try twice with $50$ each time you have $\frac 14$ chance of no rifles, $\frac 12$ chance of one rifle, and $\frac 14$ chance of two rifles.  Maybe two rifles are no better to you than one.

What you need is what other uses scraps have and what other ways there are to find the things you need.  Maybe to win you need a rifle and a vest, which also takes $100$ scraps to clone and the first player to have both wins.  If you each have $100$ scraps one strategy would be to try to find one item, then clone the other.  If you know your opponent has just found one item on his turn, you should try to clone both items.  You have $\frac 14$ chance of success and will win the game that way.  Now you can prove you should put $50$ into each item because that maximizes the probability of getting them both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew something was missing there. So it depends on the objective further down the line of the game and what the opponents are doing if your strategy is viable.